# Use devise gem for authentication in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to rails. My rails version is 4.1.6. Please suggest me some tutorials to learn authentication with devise gem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Both the devise github page and wiki are very helpful.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki

This rails cast is old but might still help you.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise